# Hadoop : start-dfs.sh Connection refused

Tags: hadoop, ssh, debian, hadoop3

I have a vagrant box on debian/stretch64
I try to install Hadoop3 with documentation 
http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.htm

When I run start-dfs.sh 
I have this message

```
vagrant@stretch:/opt/hadoop$ sudo sbin/start-dfs.sh
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
pdsh@stretch: localhost: connect: Connection refused
Starting datanodes
pdsh@stretch: localhost: connect: Connection refused
Starting secondary namenodes [stretch]
pdsh@stretch: stretch: connect: Connection refused
vagrant@stretch:/opt/hadoop$
```

of course I tried to update my hadoop-env.sh with :
export HADOOP_SSH_OPTS="-p 22"

ssh localhost work (without password)

I have not ideas what I can change to solve this problem

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I tried a command like `pdsh -w node date` and got the same error, then I did `export PDSH_RCMD_TYPE=ssh`, this solve the problem for the command on terminal, but the error using hadoop scripts, remain...

Answer (score 15):

There is a problem the way `pdsh` works by default (see edit), but Hadoop can go without it. Hadoop checks if the system has `pdsh` on `/usr/bin/pdsh` and uses it if so. An easy way get away from using `pdsh` is editing `$HADOOP_HOME/libexec/hadoop-functions.sh`

replace the line

```
if [[ -e '/usr/bin/pdsh' ]]; then
```

by

```
if [[ ! -e '/usr/bin/pdsh' ]]; then
```

then hadoop goes without `pdsh` and everything works.

**EDIT:**

A **better solution** would be use `pdsh`, but with `ssh` instead `rsh` as explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/77112/264973), so replace line from `$HADOOP_HOME/libexec/hadoop-functions.sh`:

```
PDSH_SSH_ARGS_APPEND="${HADOOP_SSH_OPTS}" pdsh \
```

by

```
PDSH_RCMD_TYPE=ssh PDSH_SSH_ARGS_APPEND="${HADOOP_SSH_OPTS}" pdsh \
```

Obs: Only doing `export PDSH_RCMD_TYPE=ssh`, as I mention in the comment, doesn't work. I don't know why...

I've also opened a issue and submitted a patch to this problem: [HADOOP-15219](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-15219)

Comment: your answer edit is very helpful!! the issue was solved

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this problem for hadoop 3.1.0 by adding

`PDSH_RCMD_TYPE=ssh`

in my `.bashrc` as well as `$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh`.

Answer (score 2):

check if your `/etc/hosts` file contains the hostname `stretch` and `localhost` mapping or not

[my `/etc/hosts` file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7SbG.png)

Answer (score 1):

Go to your hadoop home directory

**~$ cd libexec**

**~$ nano hadoop-functions.sh**

edit this line:

```
if [[ -e '/usr/bin/pdsh' ]]; then
```

with:

```
if [[ ! -e '/usr/bin/pdsh' ]]; then
```

Answer (score 1):

> Additionally, it is recommended that pdsh also be installed for better ssh resource management. —— [Hadoop: Setting up a Single Node Cluster](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html#Prerequisites)

We can remove pdsh to solve this problem.

```
apt-get remove pdsh
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the firewalls are running on your vagrant box

```
chkconfig iptables off
/etc/init.d/iptables stop
```

if not that have a look in the underlying logs /var/log/...

Comment: Unfortunately, I found nothing conclusive.
I keep looking for a solution ..
Thank you for your answer

Comment: did you find the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with my colleague's problem.
he configured ssh using hostname from the hosts file and specified ip in the workers.
after I rewrote the workers file everything worked.

~/hosts file

10.0.0.1 slave01

#ssh-copy-id hadoop@slave01

~/hadoop/etc/workers

slave01

Answer (score 0):

I added `export PDSH_RCMD_TYPE=ssh` to my .bashrc file, logged out and back in and it worked.

For some reason simply exporting and running right away did not work for me.