# Hadoop: Unable to connect to Web GUI

Tags: hadoop, installation

**Introduction:** I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS on which I'm trying to set up a Hadoop 3.2 Single Node Cluster. The installation goes perfectly fine, and I have Java installed. JPS is working as well.

**Issue:** I'm trying to connect to the Web GUI at localhost:50070, but I'm unable to. I'm attaching a snippet of my console when I execute `./start-all.sh`:

```
root@it-research:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin# ./start-all.sh
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
Starting datanodes
Starting secondary namenodes [it-research]
Starting resourcemanager
Starting nodemanagers
pdsh@it-research: localhost: ssh exited with exit code 1
root@it-research:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin# jps
6032 Jps
3154 SecondaryNameNode
2596 NameNode
```

I'm unable to resolve `localhost: ssh exited with exit code 1`

**Solutions I've tried:**
[Set up password-less SSH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39328364)
[Set up NameNode User](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48170409)
[Set up PDSH to work with SSH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48697837)

I've also added `master [myIPAddressv4Here]` in `/etc/hosts` file and tried connecting to `master:50070`. but still facing the same issue

**Expected Behaviour:** I should be able to connect to the Web GUI when I go to `localhost:50070`, but I can't.
Please let me know if there's some more information I should provide.

Comment: if your application runs fine, (check logs)
you better check firewall or iptables although you couldn't find any problem about configurations, you might missing something.
just turn off firewall or iptables and retry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The port number for Hadoop 3.x is 9870, so localhost:9870 should work.